# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforcedx, salesforce1-app

Getting below error in the console tab in on change event. I have a checkbox on click of show/hide the program based on the location checkbox.

Below is the code, Can you help me with, what am missing here Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```html
<template for:each={serviceCenterLocations} for:item="location" for:index="index">
   <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-p-bottom_xx-small slds-p-right_x-small"
        key={location.Id}>
      <div class="sc-locationbox">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td valign="top" class="slds-p-top_x-small" style="width: 18px;">
                  <lightning-input type="checkbox" value={location.Id}
                                   data-type="location" name={location.Id}
                                   data-programlocationid={location.Id}
                                   data-locationname={location.Name}
                                   onchange={handleChangeLocation}>
                  </lightning-input>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <label class="slds-radio__label" for={location.Id}>
                     <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                     <b><span class="slds-form-element__label">{location.Name}</span></b>
                     <lightning-formatted-address street={location.Address1__c}
                                                  city={location.City__c}
                                                  country={location.Country__c}
                                                  province={location.State__c}
                                                  postal-code={location.ZIP__c}>
                     </lightning-formatted-address>
                  </label>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
handleChangeLocation(event) {
    // console.log('11' + event.currentTarget.checked);
    var ischecked = event.currentTarget.checked;
    let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-type ="location"]');
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
    this.template.querySelector('[data-programlocationid = ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid + ']').checked = true;
    if (ischecked == false) {
        this.template.querySelector('[data-programlocationid = ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid + ']').checked = false;
    }
    this.tempLocation = event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid;
    this.selectedLocationId = event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid;
    // return;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.programdata.length; i++) {
        var programTypesObject = this.programdata[i].subprogram;
        for (var j = 0; j < this.programdata[i].subprogram.length; j++) {
            var subprogramObject = this.programdata[i].subprogram[j];
            for (var k = 0; k < subprogramObject.parentProgram.length; k++) {
                var parentprogramObject = subprogramObject.parentProgram[k];
                for (var l = 0; l < parentprogramObject.programs.length; l++) {
                    var programObject = parentprogramObject.programs[l];
                    if (event.currentTarget.checked == false) {
                        this.selectedLocationId = undefined;
                        programObject.showProgram = true;
                    } else if (programObject.locationId == event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid && event.currentTarget.checked == true) {
                        programObject.showProgram = true;
                    } else {
                        programObject.showProgram = false;
                    }
                  //}
                }
                var parentProgramlength = parentprogramObject.programs.filter(d => d.showProgram).length;
                if (parentProgramlength <= 0) {
                    parentprogramObject.showParentProgram = false;
                } else {
                    parentprogramObject.showParentProgram = true;
                }
            }
            var subProgramlength = subprogramObject.parentProgram.filter(s => s.showParentProgram).length;
            if (subProgramlength <= 0) {
                subprogramObject.showSubProgram = false;
            } else {
                subprogramObject.showSubProgram = true;
            }
        }
        var programTypelength = this.programdata[i].subprogram.filter(p => p.showSubProgram).length;
        // alert(programTypelength);
        if (programTypelength <= 0) {
            this.programdata[i].showProgramTypes = false;
        } else {
            this.programdata[i].showProgramTypes = true;
        }
    }
    console.log("this.after Filter" + JSON.stringify(this.programdata));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Its very hard to debug until you have a `Minimal reproducible example`. At least share what is `serviceCenterLocations`. Also please stop using `var`, use `const` or `let` whereever applicable. Also share what is in `programdata`